# Sharepoint minimum hard disk, RAM, processor requirment

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am fed up with Sharepoint. After much effort i installed Windows 7 (64 bit) for my desktop. Now when i see the Sharepoint Server 2010 requirements, it has a unpractical requirement of 80 GB free on system drive, 4 gb of RAM and 2.5 GHz per core.

I have dual core processor of Intel 2.2 Ghz, 15 GB free on system drive and 3 GB of RAM. Will Sharepoint Server 2010 install on my machine? Or do i need to again format my PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now when i see the Sharepoint Server 2010 requirements, it has a unpractical requirement of 80 GB free on system drive, 4 gb of RAM and 2.5 GHz per core.

Sharepoint isn't a toy, it's for the enterprise. The requirements aren't impractical - if you are running a Sharepoint instance foro your business you want to application to perform appropriately. Microsoft sets this minimum system requirements so their PSS don't get flooded with "My Celeron server has 20 users on Sharepoint and it runs slowly" calls.

> I have dual core processor of Intel 2.2 Ghz, 15 GB free on system drive and 3 GB of RAM. Will Sharepoint Server 2010 install on my machine? Or do i need to again format my PC?

Sharepoint Server 2010 should install and work fine on your computer. If you are the only user then Sharepoint will run appropriately for you within the resources you give it.

The only issue I have is the operating system. [This](https://web.archive.org/web/20100825092821/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint/archive/2009/05/07/announcing-sharepoint-server-2010-preliminary-system-requirements.aspx) blog posts says preliminarily that:

> ... will be 64-bit only.
> ... will require 64-bit Windows Server 2008 or 64-bit Windows Server 2008 R2.
> ... will require 64-bit SQL Server 2008 or 64-bit SQL Server 2005.

And according to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements) Windows 7 is "optional" for the `Single server with built-in database and front-end Web servers and application servers in a farm` configuration.

Comment: Thanks let me now install the Sharepoint Server. Will reply back here if everything is successful. Thanks again :).

P.S : I know Sharepoint isn't a toy :p

Comment: Sharepoint installed successfully on Windows 7 x64 :)

Answer (score 1):

You actually need 80 GB but it doens't mean that you need free 80. The requirements state that you have to provide "double" space on the hard drive of you RAM. In you case - 4*2 =16Gb plus if you have hibernation file - add some more.
Here's [a detail explanation](http://www.thesanitypoint.com/archive/2010/06/29/sharepoint-2010-and-the-c-drive.aspx).
And here is a remedy to get more space once you have SharePoint 2010 and a health warning that [you are running out of the space](http://www.sharepointdan.com/2010/05/20/sharepoint-2010-drive-space-conundrum/)